# Why my function isn't stopping at "return" line?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that will search for "Searched" directory in the directory tree and return path to it, it should stop when the directory is found, but it isn't, where is my mistake?

```py
import os
searched = "NodeBook"
def find(Path, searched):
    print("Searching in " + os.path.normpath(Path))
    for filePath in os.listdir(Path):
        if ((filePath == searched) and (os.path.isdir(os.path.join(Path, filePath)))) :
            print("Found")
            print(filePath)
            print(os.path.join(Path, filePath))
            return os.path.join(Path, filePath)
        elif (os.path.isdir(filePath)) :
            find(os.path.join(Path, filePath), searched)

find( "./", searched)
```

I expect something like that :

```
Searching in .
Searching in nodeLearning
Searching in nodeParse
Searching in Screeps
Found
NodeBook
```

But i have :

```
Searching in .
Searching in nodeLearning
Searching in nodeParse
Searching in Screeps
Found
NodeBook
./Screeps\NodeBook
Searching in testpython
Searching in testReact
Searching in testReact\testreact
```

It goes through all subdirectories.

Comment: `return` exits the currently-running instance of the function.  It doesn't affect any previous instances of the function (such as the one that made the recursive call to the current instance): those have to do a `return` of their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few small issues.

*Bug 1*: you look at `isdir(filePath)` instead of `isdir(os.path.join(Path, filePath))`.  This can cause errors if you have a file that is not a directory with the same name as a directory in your starting location.  For example

```
/tmp/a    <-- dir
/tmp/b    <-- dir
/tmp/b/a  <-- file
```

would give an `OSError`

*Bug 2*: You don't stop if you find a match in a recursive call
You can fix this in a variety of ways, chose to do this by checking the return in your recursive call.

*Bug 3*: I think this may go forever if it encounters symlinks that form a loop.  Didn't fix, but you should decide how you would handle it.

I also renamed a few things for clarity.

```
import os

def find_subdir(base_dir, search):
    print("Searching in " + os.path.normpath(base_dir))
    for name in os.listdir(base_dir):
        path = os.path.join(base_dir, name)
        if not os.path.isdir(path):
            continue
        if name == search:
            return path
        sub_search = find_subdir(path, search)
        if sub_search is not None:
            return sub_search
    return None  # For clarity

result = find_subdir( "./", "NodeBook")
if result is not None:
    print("Found")
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the function is calling itself:

```
elif (os.path.isdir(filePath)) :
    find(...)
```

Okay, but this is happening in a loop, so after this call returns, the loop *will continue*. You should rethink the logic: maybe you can check the return value and then either return it if it indicates a valid path, or continue looping otherwise.

For example, right now the function returns `None` when nothing has been found, so you can check if the return value is `None`:

```
ret = find(...)
if ret is not None:
    return ret
# continue looping otherwise
```